# Evento ao atualizar uma tabela

Tags: jquery-datatables

Bom dia pessoal, tenho um datatables que busca alguns dados por ajax, nesta mesma tela eu tenho um botão que eu gosto de deixar desabilitado e somente habilitar quando a tabela terminou de ser carregada, para isto eu utilizo o evento initComplete, vide abaixo:

```
// dados da tabela principal
$ ("#tabela_sensores_entradas").DataTable
({
        responsive: true,
        paging: false,
        language:
        {
            url: "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/Portuguese-Brasil.json"
        },
        ajax:
        {
            url: "../ajax/sensores_entradas.php",
            dataSrc: "sensores_entradas",
            data:
            {
                acao : "buscar"
            }
        },
        columns:
        [
            // 0
            {data: "id_sensor_entrada"},
            // 1
            {data: "descricao"},

        ],
        initComplete: function ()
        {
            // habilita o botão somente quando a tabela está totalmente carregada
            $ ("#botao_novo_sensor_entrada").prop ("disabled", false);
        }
```

Porém eu me deparei com um problema, quando eu faço uma atualização dos dados, utilizando o ajax.reload (), este initComplete não executa (obviamente), porque a tabela já foi iniciada. Existe algum outro evento que eu poderia adicionar ou substituir para que seja executado sempre que a requisição ajax finalizar?

Obrigado por enquanto pessoal.

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma função própria para isso. Por exemplo, crie a função:

```
function habilitaBotao(){
   $("#botao_novo_sensor_entrada").prop("disabled", false);
}
```

E chame ela no `initComplete` (sem os `()`):

```
initComplete: habilitaBotao
```

No callback do Ajax, você chama a função (com os `()`). Por exemplo:

```
success: function(data){
   habilitaBotao();
}
```

Comment: Adicionei um success ao ajax somente para ver se ele executava, desabilitou o botão corretamente mas os dados não carregaram para a tabela, devo adicionar mais alguma coisa à função?

Comment: Opa, no lugar de initComplete eu encontrei o evento drawCallback, ele faz exatamente o que eu preciso.

Comment: O ajax.reload tem um callback, que você pode chamar a função: `table.ajax.reload(habilitaBotao);`